# How find this minimum of the $k$ such $B\bigcup f(B)=X$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $f:X\rightarrow X$, $X=\{1,2...100\}$ be a function satisfying:
>
> 1) $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x=1,2...100$.

2) For any subset $A$ of $X$, $|A|=40$, we have $A\cap f(A)\neq\emptyset$

Find the minimum $k$ such that for any such function $f$, there exist a subset $B$ of $X$,

where $|B|=k$, such that $B\cup f(B)=X$.

Here $f(A)=\{x|$ there exist $y$ in $A$ such that $f(y)=x\}$

This question is  China Mathematical Olympaid  some hours ago.

This problem is very fresh

Thank you

Comment: *for any X the subset of A*, do you mean A the subset of X?

Comment: @AHH,Yes,Thank you,That's my mean

Answer (score 0):

Old Answer:

**[missing the condition $\forall A\subset X,|A|=40,(A\bigcap f(A)\neq\emptyset] )$ )

$ k=50 $:

Let $$ 1 \mapsto 2 \\ 3 \mapsto 4 \\ 5 \mapsto 6 \\...\\ 99 \mapsto 100$$
So, $$ B=\{1,3,5,...,99\} \\  f(B)=\{2,4,6,...,100\}$$
with $B\bigcup f(B)=X.$

---

Proof of $k\ge50:$

If $ k<50 \implies|B|<50, |f(B)|<50\implies|B\bigcup f(B)|<100=|X|. $

For example: if $|B|=49\implies |f(B)|\le 49 \implies|B\cup f(B)|\le98$

Therefore, $k\ge50$

---

**New Answer:** *(Correction)*

To minimize $k$ and $ |B\bigcap f(B)| $, we have to maximize $|f(B)| $

Assume $|B_1 \bigcap f(B_1)|=1$

Now, applying the idea of the Pigeonhole Principle,

$\forall B_1\subset B, |B_1|=40, |B_1\bigcap f(B_1)|=1 \implies$ The maximum size of $f(B_1)=39$

So, $$|B|=k=61$$